# Where's ejabberd.cfg file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd by downloading ejabberd.run file from the website. I didn't installed it from apt-get since it was giving some issues. I am using ejabberd version 15.04.

I need to make some changes in the configuration, but I am unable to find the configuration file. Can you tell me where's the ejabberd.cfg file saved to?

PS: I am using Ubuntu-15.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [this blog post](https://blog.process-one.net/switch-ejabberd-configuration-to-yaml/) I came to know that `ejabberd.cfg` is converted to `ejabberd.yml` and YAML is used to configure the server now. Thus no need of a cfg file.

Comment: Hello, did you replace your default cfg with the default .yml?